# Reverse DNS-style string

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

In a script running in a Debian environment, what is a good way to reverse a DNS-style string?

For example, if my script has:

```
example.org
```

What would be a good way to reverse it, so that the string would read:

```
org.example
```

A longer example:

```
www.example.org
```

should reverse to:

```
org.example.www
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative approach to build a reversed address:

- Initialize the reversed result to empty string
- While the string contains `.`

  - Extract the last segment chopping off everything from the start until a dot using parameter expansion `${var##*.}`
  - Chop off the last segment with another parameter expansion `${var%.*}`
  - Append to the reversed result the previously saved last segment

Here's one way to implement using pure Bash features:

```
rdns() {
    local s=$1
    local reversed last

    while [[ "$s" == *.* ]]; do
        last=${s##*.}
        s=${s%.*}
        reversed=$reversed$last.
    done

    reversed=$reversed$s

    echo "$reversed"
}

rdns example
rdns example.org
rdns www.example.org
```

Outputs:

> ```
> example
> org.example
> org.example.www
> ```

Answer (score 0):

this might do

```
s='www.example.org'
echo $s | tr '.' '\n' | tac | paste -sd.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sed -E 's/\./\n/g;s/$/\n/;:A;s/([^\n]*)\n(.*)(\n)(.*)/\2\3.\1\4/;tA;s/\n//'
```

Comment: This does not work correctly with more than two components.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I update my post but it's more complicated.